# How to Insert data in Table1, Table2 and Mapping_Table1_Table2 tables in single query

Tags: .net-core, ef-core-2.0, ef-core-2.1

I am using EF core 2.1. I have Table1. 1 record goes into this. Another table Table2 can have multiple records inserted and mapping_T1_T2 that will keep mapping from Table1 and Table2.
I want to do this in single request to DB through my EF and of course with transactional safely. Either all are added or all rollback in case of any exception.

Comment: please give us sample input and sample output in order to make it more clear